# Proc SQL in SAS and lag and lead

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm struggling a bit with a problem I can't quite get my head around.

Let's say we have a few columns;

IP-address, time stamp, SSN.

How would I go finding occurrences where the same IP appears in several records where the time is within the same one hour window (as an example of a window of time) and there are several SSNs.

This could for example be used for received applications for whatever, where we get a lot of traffic from one location where the data given varies.

Might lag or lead be good?

I'm using SAS, but only Proc SQL really. Might lag or lead be a way to go?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you create sample dataset for us to look at? A data step or proc is likely going to be the easier way to go about it.

Comment: Your question is interesting but you need to supply sample data and post what you've tried so people can help and so it will fall into SO rules. Please review the rules regarding posts.

Comment: At minimum post a have/want (input data and what you want the result to look like), and post how you'd go about it in code as close as you currently can get.  If it's just finding occurrences with same IP but without the time/SSN constraints, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are some uncertainty in "one hour window" description. It depends when is your starting point - one hour from when?

Otherwise you could end up with a double cycle:

- For every IP
- For every timestamp

Check if other timestamps of the same IP exists between 1 hour and with different SSN

A simpler solution might be using lag function.

- First sort by IP and time stamp.
- Second use lag to calculated new column with time difference between each two rows. Flag it when it is less than 1 hour. Use this flag in next query grouping to identify distinct SSN.

Problem with latter solution that it will mark records that are beyond 1 hour window in total.